# How can i parse Json array object using gson library

Tags: android, json, object, parsing, gson

/* This is my json file */

{
"firstname": [
"rohit",
"sagar",
"sandeep",
"rahul",
"sweta",
"priya"
]
}

/* MainActivity.java */

package com.example.gsonflow;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    InputStream data = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.safas);
    String sata = data.toString();

    Student employee = gson.fromJson(sata, Student.class);
}
```

}

/* Student.java */

package com.example.gsonflow;

public class Student {

```
private String[] firstname;


public Student(String[] firstname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("firstname");

String[] firstNameList= new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, String[].class);

List<String> allNames= new ArrayList<>();
allNames= Arrays.asList(firstNameList);

for (String name: allNames) {
   Log.d(TAG,name);
}
```